# How to find the DataGridViewCell background color in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to find the DataGridViewCell background color in C# - windows application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw this on bytes.com, and another user claims it works, though I have not tested it (this is VB):

```
DataGridView1.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Color
```

or

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color
```

Also see the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need this information in order to alter the rendering of the cell, you could plug to the Paint or the Formatting event, which EventArgs has a CellStyle property with the background color inside.